# What is difference between using Intent flag "CLEAR_TOP" and launchMode="singleTask"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

What is difference between using `Intent` flag `"FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"` & `"FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP"` and `launchMode="singleTask"`? and What is the difference in setting intent flag as  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and setting launchMode to `"singleTop"`.

Comment: have you read the relevant documentation?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have read like 5 6 medium articles and android developer docs regarding this. They have good explanation about everything. But I want to ask about the behaviour differences when setting launchModes and when setting Intentflags to an activity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understood your question from your comment you replied to Tim. So you want to know the

> behavior differences when setting launchModes and when setting
> Intentflags to an activity

Answer to your this question is that you set `launchMode` for an `Activity` inside AndroidManifest.xml file but the particular launch behavior can be changed in some ways at **runtime** through the `Intent` flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` etc.

Now lets come to your two more questions that you mentioned in your main question.

> What is difference between using Intent flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"
> & "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" and launchMode="singleTask"?

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**

When we set this flag through intent and launch that activity. In that case that activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack. A task (from the activity that started it to the next task activity) defines an atomic group of activities that the user can move to. It means it will create a separate history stack. For example, in your app you have a settings icon, when you click on that you go to settings activity where you have further activities. Here all the actions recorded will start from your setting activity only.

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**

As its name is telling clearly, if you start an Activity with this flag in a existing **task**(please understand task then everything will be very easy to understand), in that case all the activities in stack above this activity will be closed and this will become the last activity or oldest activity in the Task.

**singleTask**

When you start an activity for which you set `launchMode = "singleTask"` and there is already a task running that starts with this activity, then instead of starting a new instance the current task is brought to the front.

Your seconde question

> What is the difference in setting intent flag as
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and setting launchMode to "singleTop"?

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** and **lanuchMode = "singleTop"**

Both are have same behavior, flag is set at runtime and launchMode in AndroidManifest.xml in the beginning. The behavior is, activity this with this will be the only activity on the top in a Task. If it is already running at the top of the history stack then the activity will not be launched again.

NOTE: the best way to understand the behavior is to follow any tutorial and check it practically. Play around with code and see the behavior.

Here are some useful links:

Launch Modes : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode

Intent flags : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Comment: I found this app on the Play Store, which was invaluable in understanding concepts such as launch modes and flags, including affinity. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.eccweizhi.taskstack&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I think the Android documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` explains the difference quite well. The launch modes are quite nicely explained at https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en.